# Separating protocol parser and handler in Java

Tags: java, parsing

I am working with a simple, binary protocol. Each packet consists of 10 bytes. The first byte specifies the packet type. There are many (~50) packet types used.

I want to write a general parser for this protocol which is independent of the handling of packets. So the parser should detect the packet type and put the data into an instance of the appropriate packet class, which holds the protocol data. E.g., considering the classes below: When parser detects packet type 1 --> new Type1() and read raw bytes and set temperature and humidity. Similarly for packet type 2 and all the other packet types.

```
class Packet {
  byte[] raw;
}

class Type1 extends Packet {
  int temperature;
  int humidity;
}

class Type2 extends Packet {
  DateTime sunrise;
  DateTime sunset;
}
```

Since there are so many packet types but each application only uses very few, it should be possible to register for certain types before parsing starts. All other packets types are ignored.

I am planning to have a PacketParser for each packet type. Probably, I need a handler class for each type as well. E.g.:

```
abstract class Type1Parser {
  abstract void handle(Type1 packet);
}

class Type1Parser extends PacketParser {
  //how to use/set handler? how to pass packet to handler?
  static public Type1Handler type1Handler = null;

  @override
  void parse(Packet input) {
    if(type1Handler == null)
      return;
    Type1 packet = new Type1(input);
    packet.temperature = byteToInt(input.raw, 0, 3);
    packet.humidity = byteToInt(input.raw, 4, 7);

    type1Handler.handle(packet);
  }
}
```

How to connect parser and handler? Above a naive approach:
The program needs to implement Type1Handler and set the static variable Type1Parser.type1Handler.

Then the main parser can look like this:

```
class MainParser {
   Type1Parser type1 = new Type1Parser();
   Type2Parser type2 = new Type2Parser();
   ...
   void parse(byte[] packet) {
     switch(packet[0]) {
       case 1: type1.parse(packet); break;
       case 2: type2.parse(packet); break;
       ...
     }
   }
}
```

However, this seems to be 1) a lot of very similar lines of code 2) a lot of overhead, since all packet parser are instantiated and for each packet parse() is called, even if no handler  is registered.

Any ideas how to improve this code?

Note: The parsing should be transparent to the program. Parsing code should stay inside the "parsing library". So ideally, the program only "knows" classes TypeXHandler and TypeX.

Comment: " for each packet parse() is called, even if no handler is registered." -- seems to be necessary to call a parser, at least, to skip packets' bytes in input stream. You can read packet type and skip the rest of parsing by just skipping packet length (I assumed every packet type has fixed length).

Comment: Is handler the portion of code you want to pass the packet info off to? What is it suppose to do?

Comment: To get rid of *some* repetition in `parse` couldn't you do `PacketParser parser;` use the switch to determine and set the parser, and then out side the switch do `parser.parse(packet);`? I know it's not profound but does reduce the verbatim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, almost like torquestomp answer, here comes my code:

```
interface Packet {
}
interface PacketParser<T extends Packet> {
    Class<T> getPacketClass();
    int getPacketId();
    int getPacketLength();
    Packet parse(byte[] raw, int offset);
}
interface PacketListener<T extends Packet> {
    Class<T> getPacketClass();
    void onPacket(T packet);
}
interface PacketParsersRegistry {
    <T extends Packet> void registerPacketParser(PacketParser<T> packetParser);
    <T extends Packet> void registerPacketListener(PacketListener<T> packetListener);
}
class PacketHandlers<T extends Packet> {
    final PacketParser<T> parser;
    PacketListener<T> listener;

    PacketHandlers(PacketParser<T> parser) {
        this.parser = parser;
    }

    void setListener(PacketListener<T> listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }
}
class MainParser implements PacketParsersRegistry {
    private final HashMap<Class<?>, PacketHandlers<?>> handlers = new HashMap<>();
    private final HashMap<Integer, PacketParser> parsers = new HashMap<>();

    @Override
    public <T extends Packet> void registerPacketParser(PacketParser<T> packetParser) {
        parsers.put(packetParser.getPacketId(), packetParser);

        Class<T> packetClass = packetParser.getPacketClass();
        handlers.put(packetClass, new PacketHandlers<>(packetParser));
    }

    @Override
    public <T extends Packet> void registerPacketListener(PacketListener<T> packetListener) {
        //noinspection unchecked
        PacketHandlers<T> handlers = (PacketHandlers<T>) this.handlers.get(packetListener.getPacketClass());
        if (handlers != null) {
            handlers.setListener(packetListener);
        }
    }

    void parse(byte[] stream, int offset) {
        while (offset < stream.length) {
            int type = stream[offset];
            PacketParser parser = parsers.get(type);
            // parser m.b. != null here
            PacketListener listener = (PacketListener) handlers.get(parser.getPacketClass());
            if (listener != null) {
                Packet packet = parser.parse(stream, offset);
                //noinspection unchecked
                listener.onPacket(packet);
            }
            offset += parser.getPacketLength();
        }
    }
}
```

And here's how you can use it:

```
class HumidityPacket implements Packet {}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainParser parser = new MainParser();
        //...
        parser.registerPacketListener(new PacketListener<HumidityPacket>() {
            @Override
            public Class<HumidityPacket> getPacketClass() {
                return HumidityPacket.class;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPacket(HumidityPacket packet) {
                // todo 
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no perfect answer to this design question, and I don't wish to pretend that mine is, but hopefully my instinctual approach to this problem teaches you things you didn't already know!  The main missing component from your code that I see is Generics:

```
public interface Parser<T extends Packet> {
  T parse(Packet packet);
}

public interface Handler<T extends Packet> {
  void handle(T packet);
}
```

This way, you can use lazy static initialization to manage which packet types you are aware of.  I won't flesh out the code entirely here, but to give you an idea:

```
public class TypeRegistry {
  private static Map<Integer, TypeHandlerBundle<?>> typeHandlerBundles;

  static <T> register(int typeNum, Class<T> clazz, Parser<T> parser, Handler<T> handler) {
    // Make bundle, add to map
  }

  ... void parse(Packet packet) {
    if (typeHandlerBundles.containsKey((int) packet[0])) {
      TypeHandlerBundle<?> bundle = typeHandlerBundles.get((int) packet[0]);
      bundle.parseAndHandle(packet);
    }
  } 
}

public class TypeHandlerBundle<T extends Packet> {
  ...
  private final Parser<T> parser;
  private final Handler<T> handler;

  ... void parseAndHandle(Packet packet) {
    T parsedPacket = parser.parse(packet);
    handler.handle(parsedPacket);
  }
}

...

public class Type1Processor {
  static {
    TypeRegistry.register(1, Type1.class, TYPE1_PARSER, TYPE1_HANDLER);
  }

  // Definition of constants, implementation, etc.
  // ...
}
```

===

Things I omitted:  Qualifiers, lower level implementation, Error-checking, Synchronization, main method, etc.  Depending on your set-up, static initialization might not be the right way to call `TypeRegistry.register`, so you could instead consider a properties file that lists the classes (ugh, but has its merits), or a hard-coded sequence of calls in your main method.

Since `Parser` and `Handler` are functional interfaces here, don't forget that you can implement them with lambdas!  You can save tons of lines of code that way.

Answer (score 1):

You were right when you said that need one abstract class for parsing array of data.

```
    package parser;

    public abstract class TypeParser {  
        public  abstract void parse(byte[] arr);

    }
```

Then  for every packet type( you said that you can have 50 but if the first byte indicates the type of packet then 256 deferent types are possible), you can create class as you need for certain type eg..  Type1Parser for  type 1 Type122Parser for type 122.

```
package parser.type;

import parser.TypeParser;

public class Type1Parser extends TypeParser{    

    public void parse(byte[] array){
              // do with the bytes of array what you want
             }  
}

package parser.type;

import parser.TypeParser;

public class Type122Parser extends TypeParser {
    public void parse(byte[] arr) {}
    }
```

Then you can have one class that represents the main parser for all. If you need for every income packet to have one object for later use then you can hold it in vector.

```
package parser;

import java.util.Vector;

public class MainParser {   

    private Vector<TypeParser> vecTypeParse=new Vector<TypeParser>();   

    public void parsePacket(byte[] array){
        if(array==null || array.length<1) return; // or throw some exception        
        int typePacket=array[0]&0xff;
        String s="parser.type.Type"+String.valueOf(typePacket)+"Parser";
        TypeParser type=null;
        try {
        type=(TypeParser)Class.forName(s).newInstance(); //here you create class that you need 
        } catch(InstantiationException e) {e.printStackTrace();
        } catch(IllegalAccessException e) {e.printStackTrace();
        } catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

        // you can do something with the exceptons 
        if(type==null) return; // or throw some exception
        type.parse(array);  // here parse data for class you just created.
        this.vecTypeParse.addElement(type);     
        }

}
```